# How to disable Emmet in specific language?

Tags: sass, atom-editor, emmet

I'm using Atom as my code editor. Is there a way to disable Emmet on a specific language (like SASS)?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you have Emmet installed at all? Do you actually mean auto-completion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `unset!` on atom's `keymap.cson`, try to maintain spaces in the code block below exact (replace `sass` with desired language):

```
'atom-text-editor[data-grammar~="sass"]:not([mini])':
  'tab': 'unset!'
```

Edit: If you do not wish to disable it, you could use Emmet with a custom-command like `alt-tab` or whatever:

```
# Emmet expand customization
'atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
  'alt-tab': 'emmet:expand-abbreviation-with-tab'
```

Or change emmet tab command only in certain language:

```
'atom-text-editor[data-grammar~="sass"]:not([mini])':
  'alt-tab': 'emmet:expand-abbreviation-with-tab'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the 'tab' key will be disabled entirely. Is there any way that we can use 'tab' key normally without Emmet?

Comment: I edited an alternative to change Emmet command instead so it doesn't conflict.

Comment: 100000 likes for you :D :D :D